# Synology NAS: Volume exceeded storage capacity limit

Tags: nas, 32-bit, raid-5

i have a synology NAS with a 32bit cpu and four 6TB hdd's (usable ~5.5TB). Those four disks are bound in a raid5 storagepool (diskgroup) of 16.0TB. This storagepool contains a single volume of 15.87TB size. This setup is running for some years.

Today i received a warning message from the NAS, telling me, that due to hardware limitations the volume can only use 16TB storage capacity. The volume has exceeded the limit which might have caused data damage. Backup your volume and remove it.

BUT: There are more than 5TB unusued/free in the volume. And how can a volume, that has a fixed size of 15.87TB exceed a limit that is larger than the volume itself?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like filesystem corruption.
First of all, DON'T write anything to that volume anymore. And don't delete anything either, because deleting stuff also writes to the volume.

Then starting rescueing your data. Most important stuff first, because the situation may degrade further while you are at it.

Then contact Synology technical support for advice.
Best case they can give you instructions to check/repair the volume.
Worst case you need to delete the volume and re-create it, as the error-message already suggested.